# How to assign different length columns values of a data frame to another one knowing that I have multiple new columns to add and multiple data frames?

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple data frames in a list and a main dataframe that I want to add new values to empty existing columns in it.

I want to map certain columns from these data frames to the main data frame when matching and nan values otherwise.

new_cols = merged_df.columns[14: ]

for i in range (len(proccessed_files)):
currentDf = proccessed_files[i]

```
for col in range(len(new_cols)):
    merged_df = merged_df.set_index('Accession')
    merged_df[[new_cols[col]]] = currentDf.set_index('Accession')['H:L']
    merged_df = merged_df.reset_index()
    merged_df[[new_cols[col+1]]] = currentDf.set_index('Accession')['PVal H:L']
    merged_df[[new_cols[col+2]]] = currentDf.set_index('Accession')['Peptides(95%)']
    merged_df[[new_cols[col+3]]] = currentDf.set_index('Accession')['EF H:L']
    merged_df = merged_df.reset_index()
```

it gives me this error: ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

this code works properly

```
merged_df = merged_df.set_index('Accession')
merged_df['H:L\C4.csv'] = df1.set_index('Accession')['H:L']
merged_df = merged_df.reset_index()
```

but I have 12 columns to modify so, I do not want to write their names manually, I want to use index.